# Set Minimum date for DatePickerDialog getting IllegalArgumentException Fromdate does not precede toDate

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong? What is fromdate and what is todate? here is my code...

The max date works perfectly, so I'm really confused. It seems to me the new Date().getTime should return the right value or is it something else?

```
    meetingDateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(MapActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
                                Date date = new Date(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth - 1);
                                String dayOfWeek = simpledateformat.format(date);
                                meetingSelectDate.setText(dayOfWeek + " " + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
                            }

                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                        dpd.setTitle("Select Date:");
                        Date maxDate = new Date();
                        maxDate.setTime(new Date().getTime()+(86400000*7));
                        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate.getTime());
                        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
                        dpd.show();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime() - 10000);

this is the answer, you have to subtract a little from the time for some reason?

Comment: can't we set Min Limit to what we desired,Lets say 25/oct/2015 if it's today 23/oct/2015

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Calendar instance,and set the time.

```
long minTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + 7 * 3600000;
final Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
minDate.setTimeInMillis(minTimeMillis);
minDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, minDate.getMinimum(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
minDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minDate.getMinimum(Calendar.MINUTE));
minDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, minDate.getMinimum(Calendar.SECOND));
minDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, minDate.getMinimum(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTimeInMillis());
```